Invoke API Gateway Websocket in AWS using a HTTP request
I have a API gateway with a Websocket under a custom domain name and multiple routes integrated with a Lambda function. I am trying to make a https request to the API gateway and have it go through the $default route in the gateway to the lambda function, but I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error.
According to this doc, the API gateway should pass requests with routes that don't match any of the defined routes to the $default route, but is that only for http integrations and not lambda integrations?
I have tried using the https://{api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com and https://{api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage} url for the https request instead of my custom domain and that hasn't worked.
The gateway uses $request.body.action for route selection, and I have tried adding the action in the body as well but that also didn't help.

What is the exact 403 error message and the headers you are seeing from AWS? It will help with troubleshooting.

Update, it turns out that an API Gateway can be setup as either a Websocket API OR an HTTP API. In order to do the http calls I can't have the gateway be a websocket.

Are the variables being passed through correctly in https://{api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}? Could you try hard coding the endpoint URL first to see if it works? If that still fails, it's probably an IAM/permissions issue and you could try turning on all request logging and X-ray tracing to find out where the issue is
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-services-apigateway.html
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs

I confirmed the correct variables were being passed, I have tried both curling and calling the api from another lambda and both return forbidden. I looked at enabling X-ray but it seems to only be for RestAPIs in the API gateway, not websockets. Also the lambda has the following permissions for the api gateway "execute-api:Invoke","execute-api:ManageConnections".
